# How to automatic increase patch version after bugfix with gitversion

Tags: git, versioning, git-flow, gitversion

#### Summary

I'm setting up a new project and wanted to use GitVersion to calculate the current version of my app. What I need is semantic versioning with MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH where MAJOR and MINOR are increased with the release branch name and PATCH increases on every bugfix or hotfix merge.

At the moment I'm trying to implement GitFlow into my branching strategy, but I'll give you an explanation of what I'm doing.

1. All development is done on **develop** branch (creating a **feature/*** branch and merging back in **develop**.
2. When I want to create a release I create a **releases/[version]** branch from **develop**
3. When I find a bug in the release I create a **bugfix/*** branch and merge it back into **release/[version]** when done.
4. When no more bugs are found the **releases/[version]** will be merged in master and tagged with the correct version.

The problem is situated in step 3. When I'm for example on **releases/0.1.0** GitVersion will not increase the PATCH version after a **bugfix/*** merge. It just stays on 0.1.0 instead of the wanted 0.1.1. It does increase the commit count!

#### Steps taken so far

At the moment I'm using the following gitversion.yml file (see next title). Which includes a hotfix branch that should increment the PATCH. For some reason, after I create the **bugfix/*** branch it does not increase the PATCH when you run GitVersion on the bugfix branch, so I think I'm missing something here.

The only thing that works is setting a tag on the last commit in the **bugfix/*** branch to the new version (0.1.1-test). But because of GitVersion calculates version 0.1.0 on the bugfix branch I can't automatically upgrade the PATCH and add the needed 0.1.1-test tag on the commit.

I also thought that GitVersion would increase the version when you have a merge back into the release branch. But that's not happening as well even when I set the increment to Patch. So here as well, I'm thinking I missed something or I just want something that GitVersion isn't made for.

#### gitversion.yml

```
assembly-versioning-scheme: MajorMinorPatch
mode: ContinuousDeployment
branches:
  develop:
    tag: ''
  feature:
    tag: ''
  release:
    tag: test
    increment: Patch
    tracks-release-branches: true
    source-branches:
    - develop
    - bugfix
  bugfix:
    tag: ''
    increment: Patch
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
    regex: bugfix(es)?[/-]
    source-branches:
    - release
ignore:
  sha: []
```

#### Expected result

I would like to have the PATCH increased when I merge a **bugfix/*** branch back into my **releases/[version]** branch.

Example:

```
7f8ef13 34 minutes ago  (HEAD -> releases/0.1.0) [3]
|\
| * 3363677 34 minutes ago  (bugfix/TE-01) [2]
|/
* ac22ccb 36 minutes ago  (tag: 0.1.0-test, master, develop) [1]
```

[1] At this point I created the releases/0.1.0 branch so GitVersion should calculate 0.1.0 (which works!)

[2] Here the version doesn't matter really so it can stay 0.1.0-bug

[3] Here the version would need to be increased to 0.1.1 because we had a bugfix merge. (this is not happening!). At the moment it stays 0.1.0 but it does increase the commits count. So It will go from 0.1.0-test.0 to 0.1.0-test.2 between [1] and [3].

Maybe I'm trying to do something that's not even possible, I really don't know. So if anyone has an idea feel free to reply :)

I'm also aware that GitFlow by default doesn't have bugfix branches. But I think it's a strange idea to fix bugs directly on a release branch. Especially when you work in a larger team. That's why I'm trying to create a bugfix flow.

#### Full gitversion -diag output

```
C:\Testig gitversion>gitversion -diag
INFO [05/08/19 10:38:53:79] Dumping commit graph:
INFO [05/08/19 10:38:53:90] *   7f8ef13 49 minutes ago  (HEAD -> releases/0.1.0)
|\
| * 3363677 49 minutes ago  (bugfix/TE-01)
|/
* ac22ccb 50 minutes ago  (tag: 0.1.0-test, master, develop)

INFO [05/08/19 10:38:53:90] Working directory: C:\Testig gitversion
INFO [05/08/19 10:38:53:91] IsDynamicGitRepository: False
INFO [05/08/19 10:38:53:93] Returning Project Root from DotGitDirectory: C:\Testig gitversion\.git - C:\Testig gitversion
INFO [05/08/19 10:38:53:94] Running on Windows.
INFO [05/08/19 10:38:53:94] IsDynamicGitRepository: False
INFO [05/08/19 10:38:53:94] Returning Project Root from DotGitDirectory: C:\Testig gitversion\.git - C:\Testig gitversion
INFO [05/08/19 10:38:53:94] Project root is: C:\Testig gitversion
INFO [05/08/19 10:38:53:94] DotGit directory is: C:\Testig gitversion\.git
INFO [05/08/19 10:38:53:95] IsDynamicGitRepository: False
INFO [05/08/19 10:38:53:95] Returning Project Root from DotGitDirectory: C:\Testig gitversion\.git - C:\Testig gitversion
INFO [05/08/19 10:38:53:98] IsDynamicGitRepository: False
INFO [05/08/19 10:38:53:98] Returning Project Root from DotGitDirectory: C:\Testig gitversion\.git - C:\Testig gitversion
INFO [05/08/19 10:38:54:07] Using latest commit on specified branch
INFO [05/08/19 10:38:54:08] Running against branch: releases/0.1.0 (7f8ef13e5f43d3827d30a25f936424210cefb2c8)
INFO [05/08/19 10:38:54:09] Begin: Calculating base versions
  INFO [05/08/19 10:38:54:10] Fallback base version: 0.1.0 with commit count source ac22ccb4dd8937a5ec46ad1504281aee490b4411 (Incremented: None)
  INFO [05/08/19 10:38:54:15] Git tag '0.1.0-test': 0.1.0-test with commit count source ac22ccb4dd8937a5ec46ad1504281aee490b4411 (Incremented: 0.1.0-test)
  INFO [05/08/19 10:38:54:17] Begin: Finding branch source of 'releases/0.1.0'
    INFO [05/08/19 10:38:54:18] Begin: Finding merge base between 'releases/0.1.0' and 'develop'.
      INFO [05/08/19 10:38:54:19] Found merge base of ac22ccb4dd8937a5ec46ad1504281aee490b4411
      INFO [05/08/19 10:38:54:19] Merge base of releases/0.1.0' and 'develop is ac22ccb4dd8937a5ec46ad1504281aee490b4411
    INFO [05/08/19 10:38:54:19] End: Finding merge base between 'releases/0.1.0' and 'develop'. (Took: 5.00ms)
    INFO [05/08/19 10:38:54:19] Begin: Finding merge base between 'releases/0.1.0' and 'master'.
      INFO [05/08/19 10:38:54:19] Found merge base of ac22ccb4dd8937a5ec46ad1504281aee490b4411
      INFO [05/08/19 10:38:54:19] Merge base of releases/0.1.0' and 'master is ac22ccb4dd8937a5ec46ad1504281aee490b4411
    INFO [05/08/19 10:38:54:19] End: Finding merge base between 'releases/0.1.0' and 'master'. (Took: 0.96ms)
    INFO [05/08/19 10:38:54:19] Begin: Finding merge base between 'releases/0.1.0' and 'releases/0.1.0'.
      INFO [05/08/19 10:38:54:19] Found merge base of 7f8ef13e5f43d3827d30a25f936424210cefb2c8
      INFO [05/08/19 10:38:54:19] Merge base of releases/0.1.0' and 'releases/0.1.0 is 7f8ef13e5f43d3827d30a25f936424210cefb2c8
    INFO [05/08/19 10:38:54:19] End: Finding merge base between 'releases/0.1.0' and 'releases/0.1.0'. (Took: 1.00ms)
    INFO [05/08/19 10:38:54:20] Multiple source branches have been found, picking the first one (develop).
This may result in incorrect commit counting.
Options were:
 develop, master
  INFO [05/08/19 10:38:54:25] End: Finding branch source of 'releases/0.1.0' (Took: 85.80ms)
  INFO [05/08/19 10:38:54:33] Version in branch name: 0.1.0 with commit count source ac22ccb4dd8937a5ec46ad1504281aee490b4411 (Incremented: None)
  INFO [05/08/19 10:38:54:35] Begin: Finding merge base between 'releases/0.1.0' and 'releases/0.1.0'.
    INFO [05/08/19 10:38:54:38] Found merge base of 7f8ef13e5f43d3827d30a25f936424210cefb2c8
    INFO [05/08/19 10:38:54:42] Merge base of releases/0.1.0' and 'releases/0.1.0 is 7f8ef13e5f43d3827d30a25f936424210cefb2c8
  INFO [05/08/19 10:38:54:45] End: Finding merge base between 'releases/0.1.0' and 'releases/0.1.0'. (Took: 106.84ms)
  INFO [05/08/19 10:38:54:47] Git tag '0.1.0-test': 0.1.0-test with commit count source ac22ccb4dd8937a5ec46ad1504281aee490b4411 (Incremented: 0.1.0-test)
  INFO [05/08/19 10:38:54:49] Found multiple base versions which will produce the same SemVer (0.1.0), taking oldest source for commit counting (Version in branch name)
  INFO [05/08/19 10:38:54:53] Base version used: Version in branch name: 0.1.0 with commit count source ac22ccb4dd8937a5ec46ad1504281aee490b4411 (Incremented: None)
INFO [05/08/19 10:38:54:53] End: Calculating base versions (Took: 448.82ms)
INFO [05/08/19 10:38:54:58] Skipping version increment
INFO [05/08/19 10:38:54:60] 2 commits found between ac22ccb4dd8937a5ec46ad1504281aee490b4411 and 7f8ef13e5f43d3827d30a25f936424210cefb2c8
INFO [05/08/19 10:38:54:64] Begin: Getting version tags from branch 'refs/heads/releases/0.1.0'.
INFO [05/08/19 10:38:54:68] End: Getting version tags from branch 'refs/heads/releases/0.1.0'. (Took: 46.60ms)
```

In the end, you can see it's skipping version increment. But I have no idea why.

Comment: GitVersion is a tool which follows gitflow branching strategy, but you are not following the gitflow branching strategy, and as a result, the versions are not incrementing as you expect.  The patch version will only increment when you take a hotfix branch from the master branch, not from the release branch.  It may be that GitVersion is not the tool for what you are trying to do.

Comment: But should it not be the normal behaviour to increment the PATCH on every commit on release now with the config?

Comment: Short answer is, I don't know.  I haven't personally don't use configuration like that.

Comment: @Reggi Did you ever solve this? I have EXACTLY the same scenario and problem

Comment: @MarkCooper No never really found a good solution for this. What I do now is just increment it with git comment "+semver: patch". This way the patch will increase. But you always have to remember to add the empty commit. I did not check if updating the tool fixed the problem so worth a try maybe.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because of bug in the GitVersion task.

I had similar bug with the GitVersion task v5.0.1 that is the default version in the Azure DevOps Pipeline. GitVersion was giving me same version every single time no matter what I did with the master branch. My strategy was **Mainline**.

I've used [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=gittools.usegitversion) version of GitVersion called UseGitVersion with this task setup:

```
# Temporary fix to update GitVersionProperly
- task: UseGitVersion@5
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '0.0.0'
```

This setup installed the v5.1.2 of the GitVersion task tool and it produce correct versioning or at least according my expectation and understanding of the process.